# Getting the value of the minimum and maximum value in price filter magento

Tags: jquery, magento, interface, slider

Is there a way to obtain the minimum and maximum price/amount in magento?

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/Jquery-Range-Slider_zps87d916d4.png

The reason why i'm asking is so that when the user selects one of the options below. The price slider above will position itself. I'm not very familiar with magento so i need help in trying to understand this CMS.

I'm using a custom range slider which i got at jQuery UI. Here is the code that i have implement in magento. The functionality is incomplete.

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {

var maximumPrice = 5000;


jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider( {
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: maximumPrice,
    step:5,
    values: [ 0, 2500 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui);
        jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "Php" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - Php" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    }

});

/* Static Data
jQuery(document).on("click", "input.price_range", function(){
    var minimum = jQuery(this).attr('minimum');
    var maximum = jQuery(this).attr('maximum');
    jQuery('#slider-range').slider({ values: [ minimum, maximum ] }).change()

}).bind('slidechange',function(event,ui){ 
    jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "Php" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - Php" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
}); 
/*/


jQuery(document).on("click", "div.price-value input[value^=price]", function(){
    var minimum = jQuery(this).val();
    minimum = parseInt(minimum.split('=')[1].split('-')[0]);
    var slider = jQuery('#slider-range'); 
    var maximum =  slider.attr('maximum-price');
    jQuery('#slider-range').slider({values: [minimum, maximum] }).change()

}).bind('slidechange',function(event,ui){
    jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "Php" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - Php" + ui.values[1] );

})

if(jQuery( "#amount" )){

    jQuery(this).val( "Php" + jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - $" + jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 )
        );  
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: magento related questions are belongs to magento.stackexchange.com.

Comment: no need of sorry man. just letting you know about it :)